# Excel data constraint error with custom formula

Tags: excel, database

I wrote a formula for an excel data constraint that works in a cell. Using this formula for an excel data constraint always evaluates to false which means I keep getting an error in my custom formula for my data constraint.

I'm stuck since the formula works in a cell but not in a custom data constraint. I want the formula to only allow input that is in another table. So when a user types in a value it will give an error if it doesn't exists in another table.

Here is my formula so far

```
IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP('Table1'!A14, Table2[#All], 2,
FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)
```

Table1 is the table I want the data constraint on. Table 2 column 1 is the table I want to check if the value I enter exists in there. If the value doesn't exists in another table then I want to block the user from entering data into that cell.

Comment: Use `TRUE` in place of `FALSE` and `FALSE` in place of `TRUE` of if result not in `VLOOKUP()` part.

Comment: Reversing TRUE and FALSE still causes my data validation to evaluate to false. I'm assuming the data constraint is evaluating an error, but it gives me no information of the error and this formula works in a cell.

Comment: Also when i put an = sign in front of my formula which is what I have for my cell. I get an error when putting the = sign at the beginning of my formula in my data constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is formula in validation is not taking `Table` as range. So, use named range instead of `Table`. See the below formula. Here `MyRng` is a named range of range `Sheet1!$F$3:$G$8`

```
=IF(COUNTIF(INDEX(MyRng,,1),B3)>0,TRUE,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Will that work if my table grows and is not in that range anymore?

Comment: How could I do that but reference a table in case it grows?

Comment: You can make named range dynamic using combination of formulas.